# Power BI Guest users

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi

We have an Azure AD Tenant and External users from different organizations are added as Guest in this tenant.
When sharing content with other users, Guest users from different organization can see each other. Is there a way to prevent this enumeration? I see that a new Feature is comming wherin Guest user cannot be @mentioned

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.).This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set **guest user access is restricted to properties and memberships of their own directory objects**. This restriction level is the highest. When guests are restricted, they can only view their own user profiles but not other users.  See: [restrict guest user access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-restrict-guest-permissions).

Log in to the Azure portal as an administrator, go to **User settings**>**Manage external collaboration settings**>Select **Guest user access is restricted to properties and memberships of their own directory objects (most restrictive)**

[image]